# Methods / Tools for counting Minecraft program size

Tags: discussion, code-golf, answers, scoring

Extension of [this thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/programming-in-minecraft-redstone-how-to-measure-program-size). In this thread, please post tools or methods to count the size of programs to aid others in this process. These tools/methods should follow the counting rules listed in the corresponding meta post (link above).

Answer (score 4):

### Customizable MCEdit Filter

Edit: As @VoteToClose pointed out, the original filter did not work on mac. I have updated the repository to account for this and now there are separate mac and windows versions.

I have created an MCEdit filter to do this task, where you can customize the count for each block and select any region you want. This filter works in any Minecraft version after Infdev. Here are some screenshots:

Options:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Output:

[image]

Download this filter [here at my repository](https://github.com/GamrCorps/PPCGMinecraftByteCounter).

**Suggest features by pinging `@GamrCorps` in [The Nineteenth Byte](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) or [Mothership](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31934/mothership) (My development chat).**

Comment: Oh hay, this is your 400 rep question. :D

Comment: @VoteToClose Im glad you noticed!